# Cannot get player to move in pygame

Tags: python, list, pygame

The project I am currently working on draws a map by using a list. Each character in the list goes through a function that will draw a tile on screen. If the player hits a,s,d,w or LEFT,DOWN,RIGHT,UP the p position in the list will change and the map will be redrawn making it look like the player moved. My problem however is that this is not working. The map initially draws on the screen fine and if you click any of the button the player will move but only on the first button press, after that the player stops moving. I believe that the list isn't updating correctly but I am most likely wrong, everything I have tried to do doesn't help so I was hoping that someone here could tell me what I am doing wrong, to start the game just press one of the eight buttons. I have comments so my code is more easy to understand, thank you in advanced!

```
import random, sys, copy, os, pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption('Dungeon Escape')
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GRAY = (147, 147, 147)
ORANGE = (255, 165, 0)

DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 440))

FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()

#Pygame works where the graph has no negative
#The Y axis also starts at 0 ON TOP then GOES DOWN
XMAPCORD = 0
YMAPCORD = 0
mapNeedsRedraw = True
#This is the map 
currentLevel = [
'w','w','w','w','g','g','w','w','w','w',
'w','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','w',
'w','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','w',
'w','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','w',
'w','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','w',
'w','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','w',
'w','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','w',
'w','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','w',
'w','p','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','w',
'w','w','w','w','w','w','w','w','w','w',
]

#is responsible for drawing the map
def redrawMap():
    global XMAPCORD
    global YMAPCORD
    for i in range(0,100):
        if playerPositionMap[i-1] == 'w':
            drawWall()
            XMAPCORD = XMAPCORD + 40
        elif playerPositionMap[i-1] == 's':
            drawStone()
            XMAPCORD = XMAPCORD + 40
        elif playerPositionMap[i-1] == 'g':
            drawGoal()
            XMAPCORD = XMAPCORD + 40
        elif playerPositionMap[i-1] == 'p':
            drawPlayer()
            XMAPCORD = XMAPCORD + 40
        if i % 10 == 0:
            YMAPCORD = YMAPCORD + 40
            XMAPCORD = 0
        mapNeedsRedraw = False

#The main game loop
def movePlayer():
    global currentLevel
    global playerPositionMap
    global drawmap
    global playerPosition
    global mapNeedsRedraw

    running = True
    drawmap = True
    FPS = 30
    fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()
    playerPositionMap = currentLevel
    while running:
        #This checks to see if the user quits and the keys he presses
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.display.quit()
                sys.exit()
            #This moves the player according to the key pressed
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                #Tells python the players position in the list
                playerPosition = playerPositionMap.index('p')
                if ((event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == K_a) and (playerPositionMap[playerPosition - 1] != 'w')):
                    #Edits the p in the list
                    playerPositionMap[playerPosition - 1] = 'p'
                    playerPositionMap[playerPosition] = 's'
                    #Tells python to redraw map
                    mapNeedsRedraw = True
                elif ((event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == K_s) and (playerPositionMap[playerPosition + 10] != 'w')):
                    playerPositionMap[playerPosition + 10] = 'p'
                    playerPositionMap[playerPosition] = 's'
                    mapNeedsRedraw = True
                elif ((event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == K_d) and (playerPositionMap[playerPosition + 1] != 'w')):
                    playerPositionMap[playerPosition + 1] = 'p'
                    playerPositionMap[playerPosition] = 's'
                    mapNeedsRedraw = True
                elif ((event.key == K_UP or event.key == K_w) and (playerPositionMap[playerPosition - 10] != 'w')):
                    playerPositionMap[playerPosition - 10] = 'p'
                    playerPositionMap[playerPosition] = 's'
                    mapNeedsRedraw = True
                #Redraws the map if the player pressed a key
                if mapNeedsRedraw:
                    redrawMap()
        pygame.display.update()
        fpsClock.tick(FPS)

#The four tiles
def drawWall():
    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, WHITE, (XMAPCORD, YMAPCORD, 40, 40), 0)
def drawStone():
    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, GRAY, (XMAPCORD, YMAPCORD, 40, 40), 0)
def drawGoal():
    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, ORANGE, (XMAPCORD, YMAPCORD, 40, 40), 0)
def drawPlayer():
    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, GRAY, (XMAPCORD, YMAPCORD, 40, 40), 0)
    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, BLACK, (XMAPCORD + 10, YMAPCORD + 10, 20, 20), 0)


movePlayer()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: Also, post evidence from your debugging work.  Why aren't you *sure* whether the list is updating correctly?  A few trivial `print` statements will trace control and data flow.

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

Comment: You never reset `YMAPCORD`, so each redraw of the map is going further and further off the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Your code only accesses the 'map needs redraw' variable on events WHEN (the moment) the key is pushed. If you want to do something the entire time a key is held, use pygame.key.get_pressed or set up a pressed variable that turns true on the push event and false on the release event.